# Play youtube video by clicking overlay image

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I'm looking to have an overlay image that displays over a YouTube video, want I want is to click the overlay image which will then be removed and the video will start playing.

This is my html:

```
<div class="video-panel">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="video"><?php echo $video; ?></div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.video-panel {
 @include span(12 of 12 no-gutters);
 position: relative;
 background-color: #ccc;
 padding: 0;

.overlay {
 @include explode-width;
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: .8;
 z-index: 1;
}
}
```

I know there will be jquery needed but I have no idea on how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

```
// video gallery play on click
    $('div.videoWrapper').click(function(){
    video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).html(video);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="videoWrapper videoOnClick t-hidden m-hidden" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jy6rdnYSh74?list={your-video-id}?&amp;autoplay=1">
  <span class="play-icon"></span>
  <img class="video-overlay" src="images/video-overlay.png">
</div>
```

add you video id without the brackets.

This wont work on mobile and tablets. Will work only on a desktop or laptop.

Comment: Is there a way so it's not an iframe? I'm embedding a video so it will already have an iframe attached to it?

Comment: No really. I've done considerable amount of research on it. If you find a solution please do let me know also. Remember sharing is caring. :D

Comment: I found https://isaacwedin.com/2009/11/12/image-overlay-for-youtube-embed/ which does what I want at the basic level but it is from 2009 so quite old. Don;t know if this is useful

Comment: Well check it out. Whatever works for you is good. The answer that i have posted works for me. Try out both the solutions. All the best.